# Spark IDFModel on numbers

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

I'd like to execute TF-IDF model on a data where the "document" contents are numeric identifiers (instead of text). So I don't want to hash them, just use the numeric values instead. Any simple way to produce the org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT? Am I have to write my own non hashing HashingTF ?
Or it's simpler to calculate the tfidf on my own?

Comment: You can use **CountVectorizer** instead of **HashingTF**. **CountVectorizer** can also be used to get term frequency vectors.

Comment: That's works fine, thanks. Write it as an answer and take the credit for that ;)

Comment: I'm glad It helped :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CountVectorizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.html) instead of **HashingTF**. CountVectorizer can also be used to get term frequency vectors.

To use **CountVectorizer** and subsequently **IDF** you must use DataFrame instead of RDD, because CountVectorizer is supported only in ml package.